# Copy / Paste functions not working on first load

Tags: vb.net, tabs, vb6, com-interop

I am having an issue with the Ctrl C / Ctrl V options working in a .net Control. This .net control has many textboxes and is called via COM Interop.

Program Flow:
VB6 application creates instance of .net control with the help of Interop Control Toolkit and VBControl Extender. A new tab is created in the code jock tab manager with the .net control as the body. The first time the control is loaded Control C / Control V operations do not work at all. If you close the tab then re-open the same exact control now Control C / Control V work correctly.

If you use the right click context menu to Copy / Paste then it does work.

I have checked Code Jock forumns and didn't find anything useful.

If you add a Key_Up event and capture the Copy that works fine. But we have many .net controls that would need to be changed and doing that for every text box seems like a bad hack. And I know it works without because it works on the second load.

Comment: Why this has vb6 and vb.net tagged simultaneously?

Comment: @SomeNickName Because the exe is written in VB6 and the user control is written in .net. The .net control is accessed via com-interop

Comment: What version of VB.NET? What version of the Interop Forms Toolkit?

Answer (score 0):

do you open the tab exactly the same way when you open it the second time?

when you add a key_up event it does work on the first load? where did you add the key_up, on the tab or the .net control?
what exactly do you do in the key_up event? could you post the code?

my first guess was that it had something to do with the focus not being on the .net control or tab on first load, but that it has the focus on second load somehow ...